# How to align my Image and Text in flex using React

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, frontend

I am trying to use Flex to position my images horizontally, with the text appearing beneath each image. The image is aligned horizontally only when I comment out the texts. But with the texts uncommented, it disrupts the structure.

This is my CSS

```
.row::after{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 20px;
    /* content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table; */
}


.Image-container2{
    width: 25%;
    
}

.column img{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 5px;     
}

.Text2{
    color: red;
    font-size: smaller;
    width: 100;`
```

This is my React code:

```
typeimport React from 'react';
import "./Section2.css"

function Section2(props) {
    return (
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='column'>
                <img src={props.image} alt=''/>
             <div className='Text2'>
                <p>{props.theme}</p>
                <h2>{props.Title}</h2>
                <p>{props.By}</p>
                <p>{props.length}</p>

            </div> 
            </div>
        </div>


    );
    
}

export default Section2 here
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to create a flexbox layout to position images horizontally with text underneath each image. However, your CSS and React code have a few issues that might be causing disruption in the layout. I'll provide you with the corrected code and explain the changes.

css code:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
}

.column {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

.column img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.Text2 {
    color: red;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

react code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Section2.css';

function Section2(props) {
    return (
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='column'>
                <img src={props.image} alt=''/>
                <div className='Text2'>
                    <p>{props.theme}</p>
                    <h2>{props.Title}</h2>
                    <p>{props.By}</p>
                    <p>{props.length}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Section2;
```

Comment: The images appear vertical but the texts are positioned beneath them.

Comment: I've updated my answer you can try it again. It may help!